# CakePHP Security unlocked fields

Tags: security, cakephp, field, formhelper

Sometimes I must use `$this->Form->unlockedField();` or use attribute `secure = false`, but when I have relations (e.g. `hasMany`) and I use `input checkbox multiple` the unlocked doesn't work.

The question is: How to unlock field generated by multiple checkbox?

Comment: how you form code looks like ?.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't need a hasAndBelongsToMany relation?  I just checked my dev system and it works fine without fudging the security settings, although I can't imagine where you would need a hasMany instead of a HABTM when you are defining relationships like this.